# Porting Windows/Mac application, written in Ada, to iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ada

I am in possession of a dictionary application (takes in text as input, outputs definitions + grammar analysis). I have all the source files (about 50 pages of code), written in Ada, as well as Windows and Unix executables. I want to be able to use this dictionary in an iOS app.

I'm not at all familiar with Ada, so my question is, in a nutshell—are there any shortcuts to somehow wrap the application and use it on iOS? Or is the only way just re-writing the entire application in C/Objective-C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shark8 mentioned JVM-targeted Ada. ACT sells a version of Gnat that targets the JVM. However, **I do not believe iOS devices currently run Java**. Apple does not want to lose control of the platform, so they do not allow any development environments other than their own, which is Objective C based. I understand the Java folks are working to fix this, but even if they do Apple will probably refuse to allow any such app into their online store. Note that this is not a problem unique to Ada. Any app written in any language other than C or Objective C has the same problem with iOS. (This is one of the many reasons why developers tend to prefer to target Android platforms than iOS).

So what you really need is something that can get your code compilable with Apple's Objective C compiler. Supposedly Objective C is a strict superset of C. If this is true for Apple's implementation, then an Ada compiler that outputs compilable C sources should do the job for you.

Fortunately, there is such an Ada compiler (or at least there used to be). **AdaMagic** at one point had C available as a "target". It is now sold by [SofCheck](http://www.sofcheck.com/products/adamagic.html). When last I saw a discussion of it years and years ago, they referred to it as a "service" as much as a compiler, so it may not be cheap. But if you have a real business need, it would certainly be cheaper than spending man-years rewriting a working app.

Your other option of course would be to say "Screw Apple and their facist OS", and shoot for Android instead. Sadly, for business reasons, that may not be feasible. :-(

*Update (2016/2012)*: The assets of SofCheck have become available from AdaCore, as the two companies [have merged](http://www.adacore.com/press/adacore-sofcheck-merge) in early 2012.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to be able to use this dictionary in an iOS app.

Well, if there is an Ada compiler that targets iOS -- and there probably is considering that GCC has an Ada front-end -- then re-using the packages should be straight-forward so long as the source isn't compiler- (for a different compiler) or architecture-specific.

The most experience I have with porting Ada to other architectures was to port some code I had compiling to the native machine to the JVM (there's an Ada compiler which targets the JVM); the "gotchas" were more along the line of the JVM's case-sensitivity interacting with Ada's case insensitivity for naming classes and packages.